# Null check operator used on a null value (error)

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

This is the code:

```
 ​// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables 
  
 ​import​ ​'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart'​; 
 ​import​ ​'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart'​; 
 ​import​ ​'package:flutter/material.dart'​; 
 ​import​ ​'package:google_nav_bar/google_nav_bar.dart'​; 
 ​import​ ​'package:projectciplified/screens/read%20data/get_user_name.dart'​; 
  
 ​class​ ​HomePage​ ​extends​ ​StatefulWidget​ { 
 ​  ​const​ ​HomePage​({​Key​?​ key}) ​:​ ​super​(key​:​ key); 
  
 ​  ​@override 
 ​  ​State<​HomePage​>​ ​createState​() ​=>​ ​_HomePageState​(); 
 ​} 
  
 ​class​ ​_HomePageState​ ​extends​ ​State<​HomePage​>​ { 
 ​  ​final​ user ​=​ ​FirebaseAuth​.instance.currentUser​!​; 
  
 ​  ​//document ids 
 ​  ​List<​String​>​ docIDs ​=​ []; 
  
 ​  ​// method to get document ids 
 ​  ​Future​ ​getDocID​() ​async​ { 
 ​    ​await​ ​FirebaseFirestore​.instance.​collection​(​'users'​).​get​().​then​( 
 ​          (snapshot) ​=>​ snapshot.docs.​forEach​( 
 ​            (document) { 
 ​              ​print​(document.reference); 
 ​              docIDs.​add​(document.reference.id); 
 ​            }, 
 ​          ), 
 ​        ); 
 ​  } 
  
 ​  ​@override 
 ​  ​Widget​ ​build​(​BuildContext​ context) { 
 ​    ​return​ ​Scaffold​( 
 ​      appBar​:​ ​AppBar​( 
 ​        title​:​ ​Text​( 
 ​          user.email​!​, 
 ​          style​:​ ​TextStyle​(fontSize​:​ ​16​), 
 ​        ), 
 ​        actions​:​ [ 
 ​          ​GestureDetector​( 
 ​              onTap​:​ () { 
 ​                ​FirebaseAuth​.instance.​signOut​(); 
 ​              }, 
 ​              child​:​ ​Icon​(​Icons​.logout)), 
 ​        ], 
 ​      ), 
 ​      bottomNavigationBar​:​ ​Container​( 
 ​        color​:​ ​Colors​.black, 
 ​        child​:​ ​Padding​( 
 ​          padding​:​ ​const​ ​EdgeInsets​.​symmetric​( 
 ​            horizontal​:​ ​15​, 
 ​            vertical​:​ ​20.0​, 
 ​          ), 
 ​          child​:​ ​GNav​( 
 ​            backgroundColor​:​ ​Colors​.black, 
 ​            color​:​ ​Colors​.white, 
 ​            activeColor​:​ ​Colors​.white, 
 ​            tabBackgroundColor​:​ ​Colors​.blue, 
 ​            padding​:​ ​EdgeInsets​.​all​(​10​), 
 ​            gap​:​ ​2​, 
 ​            onTabChange​:​ (index) {}, 
 ​            tabs​:​ [ 
 ​              ​GButton​( 
 ​                icon​:​ ​Icons​.home, 
 ​                text​:​ ​'Home'​, 
 ​              ), 
 ​              ​GButton​( 
 ​                icon​:​ ​Icons​.favorite_border, 
 ​                text​:​ ​'likes'​, 
 ​              ), 
 ​              ​GButton​( 
 ​                icon​:​ ​Icons​.search, 
 ​                text​:​ ​'search'​, 
 ​              ), 
 ​              ​GButton​( 
 ​                icon​:​ ​Icons​.settings, 
 ​                text​:​ ​'settings'​, 
 ​              ), 
 ​            ], 
 ​          ), 
 ​        ), 
 ​      ), 
 ​      body​:​ ​Center​( 
 ​        child​:​ ​Column​( 
 ​          mainAxisAlignment​:​ ​MainAxisAlignment​.center, 
 ​          children​:​ [ 
 ​            ​Expanded​( 
 ​                child​:​ ​FutureBuilder​( 
 ​              future​:​ ​getDocID​(), 
 ​              builder​:​ (context, snapshot) { 
 ​                ​return​ ​ListView​.​builder​( 
 ​                  itemCount​:​ docIDs.length, 
 ​                  itemBuilder​:​ (context, index) { 
 ​                    ​return​ ​Padding​( 
 ​                      padding​:​ ​const​ ​EdgeInsets​.​all​(​8.0​), 
 ​                      child​:​ ​ListTile​( 
 ​                        tileColor​:​ ​Colors​.grey[​200​], 
 ​                        title​:​ ​GetUserName​(documentID​:​ docIDs[index]), 
 ​                      ), 
 ​                    ); 
 ​                  }, 
 ​                ); 
 ​              }, 
 ​            )), 
 ​          ], 
 ​        ), 
 ​      ), 
 ​    ); 
 ​  } 
 ​}
```

I'm trying to get the user info with ​FirebaseAuth​.instance.currentUser! but it's giving said error.
With ​FirebaseAuth​.instance.currentUser (without the !) The code works but why?

Can someone explain the null error? I'm not sure why this code doesn't work as it worked around 5 hours ago. How do I fix it? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There are few  states `FutureBuilder` provides, like connection state, error state and data or empty state. While you calling future it needs some time to fetch data, means first state is loading state and data is not ready yet. That's why it says null error because we don't have any data.

Do like

```dart
FutureBuilder(
  future: ​getDocID​(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return Center(child: Text('Please wait its loading...'));
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
    } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return ListView(...);
    }
    else return Text("dont have any data")
  },
```

Find more about `FutureBuilder` on [flutter.dev](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

Comment: The futurebuilder isn't the problem in this case. I forgot to remove it from my post code, FirebaseAuth​.instance.currentUser! which is the problem here.

Comment: Can you check if the current user is available doing null check on `user` you can try printing/debug this variable